# SQL Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
Parent_Org  bit Unchecked
HQ          bit Unchecked
Existing    bit Unchecked
Prospects   bit Unchecked
```

These are the columns in my table but i am getting error.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

I am using MS Sql server management studio

Comment: Post your table's DDL and the script you're running when you get the error.  What you've written above doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "`Unchecked`"? That isn't a property of a the `bit` datatype. a `bit` can have the value `1`, `0`, or `NULL`. `Unchecked` isn't a value it can hold.